# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout - center items in sections or groups

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I set up a collection view and its layout with the new compositional stuff and it has been pretty cool, it seems to be very expandable but I can't find a way to make items centered in the collection, which is IMO a basic feature that one would imagine being supported..

What I have is:

[image]

Accomplished with this code:

```swift
UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { section, env in
    let tagDefaultSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 40)
    
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(tagDefaultSize.width), heightDimension: .absolute(tagDefaultSize.height))
    )
    
    item.edgeSpacing = NSCollectionLayoutEdgeSpacing(
        leading: .fixed(0),
        top: .fixed(0),
        trailing: .fixed(8),
        bottom: .fixed(0)
    )
    
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(tagDefaultSize.height)),
        subitems: [item]
    )
    
    group.edgeSpacing = NSCollectionLayoutEdgeSpacing(
        leading: .flexible(8),
        top: .fixed(0),
        trailing: .fixed(8),
        bottom: .fixed(8)
    )
    
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(
        top: 30,
        leading: 20,
        bottom: 40,
        trailing: 20
    )
    
    return section
}
```

But what I need is this:

[image]

Has anyone had any luck with this? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588283/how-to-center-align-the-cells-of-a-uicollectionview 2nd solution can help you

Comment: Thank you, that is in fact the solution I will rely on if nothing is doable with compositional layout

Comment: @nknr Did you ever find a solution to this, using compositional layout?

Comment: @AshleyMills IIRC sadly, no. I think I just trashed that and went with a classical layout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution for this, using

```
custom(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize, itemProvider: @escaping NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItemProvider)
```

I created the following extension, which calculates the frames of each element in the group, centring as many items as will fit on each row

```
extension NSCollectionLayoutGroup {

    static func verticallyCentered(cellSizes: [CGSize], interItemSpacing: CGFloat = 10, interRowSpacing: CGFloat = 10) -> NSCollectionLayoutGroup {
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(100))
        return custom(layoutSize: groupSize) { environment in
            var items: [NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem] = []
            
            var yPos: CGFloat = environment.container.contentInsets.top
            
            var rowSizes: [CGSize] = []
            
            func totalWidth() -> CGFloat {
                rowSizes.map(\.width).reduce(0) {
                    $0 == 0 ? $1 : $0 + interItemSpacing + $1
                }
            }
            
            func addRowItems() {
                var xPos = (environment.container.effectiveContentSize.width - totalWidth())/2 + environment.container.contentInsets.leading
                let maxItemHeight = rowSizes.map(\.height).max() ?? 0
                let rowItems: [NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem] = rowSizes.map {
                    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos + (maxItemHeight - $0.height) / 2), size: $0)
                    xPos += ($0.width + interItemSpacing)
                    return NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem(frame: rect)
                }
                
                items.append(contentsOf: rowItems)
            }
            
            for (index, cellSize) in cellSizes.enumerated() {
                rowSizes.append(cellSize)
                
                if totalWidth() > environment.container.effectiveContentSize.width {
                    rowSizes.removeLast()
                    addRowItems()
                    yPos += (cellSize.height + interRowSpacing)
                    rowSizes = [cellSize]
                }
                
                if index == cellSizes.count - 1 {
                    addRowItems()
                }
            }
            return items
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a layout section with a single group that contains all the items in that section. First you'll first need to calculate the sizes of all the elements in the section, and then pass those in to the function above, something like this (note that I'm using a DiffableDataSource here)…

```
func someLayoutSection(sectionIndex: Int) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    let itemCount = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: sectionIndex)
    let cell = SomeCell(frame: .zero)
    let cellSizes: [CGSize] = (0..<itemCount).compactMap {
        switch diffableDataSource.itemIdentifier(for: IndexPath(item: $0, section: sectionIndex)) {
        case let .someItem(something):
            cell.configure(thing: something)
            return cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.verticallyCentered(cellSizes: cellSizes)
    group.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20).scaled
    
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 0, bottom: 20, trailing: 0)
    return section
}
```

and then create the layout…

```
func makeLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { [unowned self] sectionIndex, environment in

        let section = diffableDataSource.snapshot().sectionIdentifiers[sectionIndex]

        switch section {
        case .someSection:
            return someLayoutSection(sectionIndex: sectionIndex)
        case .otherSection:
            // etc
        }
    }
```

Comment: looks good! 
(minor, but shouldn't it be `.horizontallyCentered()`?)
either way, thanks

Comment: This is incredible! Do you have any idea how to get this to work as a subgroup inside an orthogonal section? As it is it looks like it only works vertically.

I tried to get it to work by just resetting the yPos and paging over and it doesn't quite work :\

Comment: For varying hight cells verticallyCentered func need a fix to update the yPos correctly in  loop over `cellSizes.enumerated()`:

- `yPos += (cellSize.height + interRowSpacing)`
+ `let maxItemHeight = rowSizes.map(\.height).max() ?? cellSize.height`
+ `yPos += (maxItemHeight + interRowSpacing)`